# What will replace the .bib file?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

The `.bib` file feels like a bit of a hacked together kludge. I mean, it works, but it ain't pretty, and it has some odd limitations. It feels like a replacement, built from the ground up to make the most of the power of biber and biblatex would be an obvious move.

Put the question a different, perhaps less provocative, way: `biblatex` seems to be built in such a way that alternatives to `.bib` files can be used. What alternatives are there that can be used in this way? The `.bib` format was in place well before work on biblatex started, so `.bib` files are not built for use with biber and biblatex. Presumably, if they were starting from scratch, they would do things differently with a custom-built bibliography database format for biblatex/biber. What would such a format look like? Has anyone tried to do this?

Comment: I have added a `future` tag, but I can't say I really know whether it's a good idea. Anyway, if it is, I get another shiny taxonomist badge

Comment: I don't know what problem you have with a BibTeX format. The question seems very unclear to me and I would say it quite falls into the "not constructive" category.

Comment: a `bib` file is a data base with an open structure. Why should it be limited?

Comment: @AndrewSwann: that is not a limitation of the bib file. It is or was a limitation of the program `bibtex`

Comment: I assume by limitations here you mean things like the fact that a publish list `Publisher A and PublisherB` plus  location list `PlaceA and PlaceB` does not show the detailed relationship. If that's what you are after, there are various formats we can point to. However, for many people these things are not an issue (the level of detail is not needed), and so it's not entirely clear that anything needs to replace `.bib` for most users.

Comment: I don't have any particular limitations in mind (although I'm sure I've seen people on here air greivances about things `.bib` files make difficult for biber etc). I hope that the edit makes clear that I am trying to ask a constructive question about the future of bibliography database formats.

Comment: Probably an XML based format would overcome many of the limitations of the `.bib` format; for instance the order of names in different languages or tagging entries with the proper language code. I don't know what's the status of Biber in this direction. Of course, humans can write a `.bib` file, which is not true for XML.

Comment: I guess the kind of information that is encoded in the .bib files can be very much considered as semantic information. 

Therefore, I very much see a future for the use of semantic databases in combination with tools like biblatex, which could add a lot more flexibility to the format (although it already is very flexible) and could make it also way more powerfull by adding the possibility to infer information. 

So I guess I would say XML semantic formats like RDF for example.

Comment: @egreg Why can't humans write XML files? There are enough people who write HTML, which is (most of the time) XML.

Comment: @egreg: there's no reason humans shouldn't write xml files, but the format isn't designed for that.  back when bibtex was invented, we tailored our input formats to what we could practically parse, so it's no surprise that oren's design looks odd.  now, _i_ write xml regularly, which we use because it's there; "modern" users might prefer to use a tailored xml (semantic) editor, but i get by with emacs and a post-edit checker.  this attitude doesn't seem to me to scale, but i suspect that xml is the way to go for biber input nonetheless.

Comment: @wasteofspace I too see XML as the obvious road. What's needed is a tool that allows "normal people" (those who can't write deeply nested XML files directly with a keyboard) to input data when needed. Of course, the power of modern information techniques we have today seems promising.

Comment: biber supports the experimental biblatexml xml format for these reasons. I have to do some work on this and document it though.

Comment: An alternative to XML is JSON. It's far easier to parse for humans. In fact some NoSQL database solutions such as mongodb and couchdb use JSON, partly for this reason.